# JWT spring security Authentication filter losts headers information

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I've made REST Security with JWT using Spring Security basis according to this article - https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java

In particular, I have filter that authenticates users using token from "Authorization" header of request:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

public JwtAuthenticationFilter() {
    super("/**");
}

@Override
protected boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

    String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        throw new JwtTokenMissingException("No JWT token found in request headers");
    }

    String authToken = header.substring(7);

    JwtAuthenticationToken authRequest = new JwtAuthenticationToken(authToken);

    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);

    // As this authentication is in HTTP header, after success we need to continue the request normally
    // and return the response as if the resource was not secured at all
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
}
```

So, when processing request my filter every time do not find Authorization and any other Headers information in HttpServletRequest object and app gives answer that user is not authenticated.
When I deactivate JWT Security Filter the same request has all Headers in it.

Has anyone any ideas in How can I fix this problem?

my config file is:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">

<!--activate @PreFilter, @PreAuthorize, @PostFilter, @PostAuthorize annotations on any spring beans in the context-->
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<!--define the login and signup endpoints to skip security-->
<http pattern="/authenticate" security="none"/>

<!--we define the filter chain applied to all requests while adding two important configs: Entry point reference and -->
<!--setting the session creation to stateless (we do not want the session created for security purposes as -->
<!--we are using tokens for each request)-->
<http pattern="/**" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="stateless">
    <!--We do not need csrf protection because our tokens are immune to it-->
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <!--we plug in our special authentication filter within the Spring’s predefined filter chain,-->
    <!--just before the form login filter-->
    <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="jwtAuthenticationFilter"/>
</http>

<!--This bean is the declaration of our authentification filter; since it is extending Spring’s -->
<!--AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter, we need to declare it in XML to wire its properties -->
<!--(auto wire does not work here)-->
<beans:bean id="jwtAuthenticationFilter" class="by.eventcat.rest.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <!--The default success handler of AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter is not good enough for REST purposes -->
    <!--because it redirects the user to a success page; that is why we set our own here-->
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="jwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!--The declaration of the provider created by the authenticationManager is used by our filter to authenticate users-->
    <authentication-provider ref="jwtAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="by.eventcat.rest.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
<beans:bean id="jwtAuthenticationProvider" class="by.eventcat.rest.security.JwtAuthenticationProvider"/>
<beans:bean id="jwtUtil" class="by.eventcat.rest.security.JwtUtil"/>
```

Comment: can i have a look at your security config?

Comment: Yes, i'll edit my question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added to my application CORS configuration, that influence not only on responce BUT ON REQUEST. So, to my web.xml I've added:

```
<!--CORS configuration--> 
<filter>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>by.eventcat.rest.MyCorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And MyCorsFilter is:

```
public class MyCorsFilter extends CorsFilter {

public MyCorsFilter() {
    super(configurationSource());
}

private static UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
}

}
```